# best way to add multiple child records at once?

Tags: gui-design, master-details

I have a system in which Procedures can be defined. 
Each Procedure has a series of steps (each step having some attributes)

It is reasonable to assume that the user will add all of the steps while creating the procedure.

My current approach is using an excel-like grid to enable fast input of the steps.

```
Procedure Name
[Some Name...]

Steps
Name      | Expected Time | Is Invoiced?
------------------------------------
Step 1    | 1 day         | [X]
Step 2    | 2 days        | []
add new...
```

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2vTJT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I would like to know if this sounds resonable or if there is a better way to solve this problem.

As far a I know, the average procedure has 10-20 steps, and each step can have more than 3 attributes... (although only the Step's name is required)

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for showing me how to include the mockup!!

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, assuming those columns have fixed meanings, it looks like a good solution.  I've worked on something similar, a procedure specified in a table, and although it required some training (it was a complicated, domain heavy application) it was successful from a usability point of view.  (Hitting the "Enter" key causes a new step to be added, right?)

Comment: A new step placeholder is available at all times. As soon as there is something on the name column, a new row becomes available.